# display content in taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

hope you can help me with this, i wanted to display the content in my custom post type, taxonomy, I created my own template for archive.php  heres the code

```
    <div id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php if (is_tax( 'location' )) :?>
            <div class="offer-content">
                <div class="offer-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                <div class="offer-desc">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
               </div> 
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

i tried using the_content but it keeps on  displaying the content in post, not onn the custom post type that i created..

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<?php if (is_tax( 'location' )) :?>
```

TO

```
<?php if (is_tax( 'location' ) && ( 'your_custom_post' == get_post_type() )) :?>
```

May this help you.....

Comment: oh, got the solution on this , i have to query the post first